# Search and replace different values in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I search and replace in way described below. I would like have texts between `>` and `<` from this text:

```
<option value="something">Text a</option>
<option value="abc">Test</option>
<option value="abc1">System</option>
```

After search and replace I would like have:

```
Text a+Test+System
```

So for `</option>` I can do Search and Replace like that:

`</option>\r\n`   replace to     `+`

But how can I search and replace texts contains different value in here: `<option value="something">`? I tried with

```
<option value="*">
```

but it seems not working.

Can I do these two Search and Replace in one Search and Replace dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in two simple steps:

First search for `<option value=".*">` and select the search mode to regular expression and replace it with empty string.

Secondly, replace `</option>\r\n` with `+` and use the search mode extended for this replacement.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. But is it possible to do these two Search and Replace in one?

Comment: @Lucas It is not possible to search and replace the carriage return and line feed characters using Notepad++ Regular Expression search mode. As Notepad++ uses Scintilla regex engine and per Scintilla documentation "... \r and \n are never matched because in Scintilla, regular expression searches are made line per line (stripped of end-of-line chars).". See following URL for more information [http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html)

Comment: @JawwadAlam Recent versions of Notepad++ allow `\r` and `\n` in regular expressions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946 for links to documentation.

Comment: @Lucas See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389466/multiple-word-search-and-replace-in-notepad/16104946#16104946 for a way of combining these two replacements into one.

Answer (score 4):

You do it like this:

[image: notpad++ search dialog]

Make sure Regular Expression is selected.

`<option value="(.*)">(.*)<` matches your option, the first `.*` matches everything between the `"` 
Place that in side parenthesis `(.*)` which will create a group you later can refer to. Similarly,
the 2. `(.*)` creates the 2. group, which matches the text between the `>` and `<`

Then replace the matched text, using `\1` and `\2` to refer to the two captured groups:
`<option value="\1">\2 test system<`

Comment: Thanks for advice. Because of your advice I found better way: `<option value="(.*)">(.*)</option>` replace to `\2+`. But there is still a line break.

Comment: After `<option value="(.*)">(.*)</option>`. I tried with `<option value="(.*)">(.*)</option>\r\n` but search not working during Regular Expression search.

Comment: @Lucas It is not possible to search and replace the carriage return and line feed characters using Notepad++ Regular Expression search mode. As Notepad++ uses Scintilla regex engine and per Scintilla documentation "... \r and \n are never matched because in Scintilla, regular expression searches are made line per line (stripped of end-of-line chars).". See following URL for more information [http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Step 1*: In the replace dialog, switch the search mode to  "Regular expression", Search ^<.+\"> and then replace with an empty string.

*Step 2*: Switch the search mode to normal, Search </option>  and replace with an empty string

*Step 3*. Switch the search mode to Extended(\n, \r ...) search \r\n and replace with +

Good luck.

Comment: Works. But is it possible to do these two Search and Replace in one Search and Replace dialog?